# yeoman can't edit XML file that was created by other sub generator

Tags: xml, node.js, xml-parsing, yeoman, fs

I'm trying to make changes to a XML File in one sub generator that was created by another one.

My Main generator does the prompting and determines which subgenerators should be used. Simplyfied it looks like this:

```
var MainGenerator = module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
  writing: function () {
    this.composeWith('design:setup', {});
    if (this.option.get('someOption')) {
      this.composeWith('design:extend', {});
    }
  }
});
```

The Setup Generator adds some files that are used in every variation of the design. For example a project config.xml

```
var SetupGenerator = module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
  default: function () {
    // ^ default: makes sure the vsSetup is run before the writing action
    //   of the other sub generators
    this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath( 'project/_config.xml' ),
      this.destinationPath( 'project/config.xml' )
    );
});
```

Now, depending on the settings the user chose in the prompts, different sub generators are executed. When every they add a new folder to the destination, this has to be updated in the config.xml that was created by the setup generator.

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var MainGenerator = module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
  writing: function () {
    var xmlParser = new xml2js.Parser();
    this.fs.read( 'project/config.xml', function (err, data) {
      console.log('read file');
      console.dir(err);
      console.dir(data);

      xmlParser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.log('parsed xml: ' + 'project/config.xml' );
        console.dir(result);
        console.dir(err);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

There is no output at all from fs read. No Error, no Nothing.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Because there are different combinations of extending generators I want to have each generator register the folders it needs rather then having a unmaintainable hell of `if else` statements in the original xml file.

Comment: The question still stands how to edit an xml. But just in case some finds this in google: I've changed my architecture so I don't have to alter the xml file. Now the sub generators register the files that need to be registerd in the xml to an array and the main generator write them all into the file as usual with this.fs.copyTpl()

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found much documentation on any events being emitted by the file system, or from the `composeWith` function, but you can hook into the `end` event and read the file then.

```
this.composeWith('design:extend', {})
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log(this.fs.read('path/to/file'));
        // do your file manipulation here
    });
```

It's not the best way to go about it as it is modifying a file *after* it is committed to disk, and not in the in memory editor, but this is at least a good place to start.

Comment: thanks adam, this might come in handy some time.I've since changed my generator so it first collects all the needed data and then writes it to the xml file at one central point in the code.